# SQL Server address to connect using php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I use this code to connect to SQL Server 2012, but it does not work

```
<?php
$objConnect = mssql_connect("localhost","usr","pass"); 

if($objConnect)  
{  
  echo "Database Connected.<br />";  
  echo mssql_error();
}  
else  
{  
  echo "Database Connect Failed.<br />";
}  

mssql_close($objConnect);  
?>
```

It always prints `Database Connect Failed.`

Also how can I connect to my local SQL Server from an external web server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your edition is SQL Server Express, you should probably be using:

```
$objConnect = mssql_connect("localhost\SQLEXPRESS","usr","pass");
```

Or if it is otherwise a named instance, then

```
$objConnect = mssql_connect("localhost\InstanceName","usr","pass");
```

If you need to connect remotely, then obviously you shouldn't be using `localhost` since how does the remote web server locate *your* `localhost`? You should be using one of the following (assuming the remote web server can see your machine with IP address 192.168.5.22):

```
$objConnect = mssql_connect("192.168.5.22\SQLEXPRESS","usr","pass");
$objConnect = mssql_connect("192.168.5.22\NamedInstance","usr","pass");
$objConnect = mssql_connect("192.168.5.22","usr","pass");
```

Of course your firewall must have port 1433 (and possibly 1434) open in order to accept that connection, and there are a variety of other things that can go wrong here as well.

However, a little debugging 101 suggestion. Instead of:

```
if($objConnect)  
{  
  echo "Database Connected.<br />";  
  echo mssql_error();
}  
else  
{  
  echo "Database Connect Failed.<br />";  
}
```

Why not:

```
if($objConnect)  
{
  echo "Database Connected.<br />";  
}  
else  
{  
  echo "Database Connect Failed.<br />";  
  echo mssql_error();
}
```

Surely you don't need to write an error to the page when the database connects successfully. And telling us the actual error message you receive may better equip us to point you in the direction of a solution. A generic "Database Connect Failed" message that you wrote is not going to give anyone any clue about what actually went wrong. But I bet `mssql_error()` might!

Comment: my instance name is MSSQLSERVER , and still does not connect and msql_error() does not display any thing, can you help please ?thanks for the answer

Comment: Sorry, I can't help if you can't tell me what the error is. Does the `mssql_error()` function, or something leading up to this point, have try/catch or other potential handlers that drop errors on the floor?

Comment: thanks I added 1434 to the servername, localhost:1434\MSSQLSERVER and it works, but the external server does not work

Comment: The other server has to be able to see the server where SQL Server is running. So as I said you can't say `localhost` except in cases where the web server and database are on the same machine. When you say "external server" can you be a lot more specific? Is this server in your domain, somewhere else in your house, out on a hosted server somewhere...? Why are you hosting your database locally and connecting a remote web server to it? Usually people do the opposite. Also if the SQL Server browser service is running you shouldn't have to specify a port number - not sure why 1434 vs. 1433 either.